# Update DataGrid to EF

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I display data into `DataGrid` in this way:

```
var display = (from r in ve.Folders.Include("Hosting_Company1")
               select new RepoClass{ id = r.Folder_Id,name= r.Full_Name, hosName= r.Hosting_Company1.Housing_Name }).ToList();

dg1.ItemsSource = display;
```

and in the `XAML`:

```
<DataGrid CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="dg1">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=id, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="id"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=name, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="Name" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=hosName, Mode= TwoWay}"  Header="company" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

How do I then update the data into the `EF`?

Comment: What data do you update? If `hosName` is updateable you can introduce ambiguity because it will be repeated in the grid. Anyway, after updating values in the grid you will have to write the changes to the original entities and `SaveChanges`.

Comment: @GertArnold Sorry, I didn't really get it.

Comment: When the user changes a name in the grid and presses the save change button the changes are not saved. How can I get the changes to be saved?

Answer (score 0):

If ve is your datacontext, then you need to call ve.SaveChanges().  I usually pass an observable collection to the datagrid so that changes are easier to manage.